# foreach gives startindex error

Tags: datagridview, bindinglist

following code gives a "Value of '7' is not valid for 'indexStart'. 'indexStart' must be less than or equal to 3. Parameter name: indexStart" error!

```
void eventsource_EventLogCollectionChanged(object sender, EventLogEventArgs e)
        {
            _all.AddRange(e.NewEventLogItems);

            BindingList<EventlogItem> data = dgvPlcEvents.DataSource as BindingList<EventlogItem>;
            List<EventlogItem> newdata = FilterEvents((EventLogItemType)cboEventTypes.SelectedItem, GetSidFilter(), e.NewEventLogItems).ToList();
            foreach(EventlogItem item in newdata)
            {
                data.Add(item);
            }

            dgvPlcEvents.Invalidate();
        }
```

1) Why?
2) how can I fix it?

I transfered the bindinglist (getting from filterevents) to a list to avoid the error but it didn't helped.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to add some items to a bindinglist that is the datasource for a datagridview so it would auto insert rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your datasource is set to `AllowNew = true;`
set it to `AllowNew = false;` then add your item.